# Push notification using FCM does not work but Onesignal

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

sending push notification from Onesignal working fine but FCM.

【What I`m Doing】

I am implementing push notification using FCM following published documentation from firebase.

【What I have tried】

・checking required Certificates.(verified using Onesignal. receiving push notification from Onesignal is working fine)

・provisioning files is newest.

・Certificates`s password is correct.

・testing is in development environment.(In ad-hoc environment does not work).

・all Related cache for xcode are cleard.

【What I would like to know】

How to receive push notification using FCM and what I`m missing so far.

【codes is below】※ codes review would be huge help and greatful for me please !!

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Firebase
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FacebookCore
import FirebaseDatabase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging
import OneSignal
import CallKit
import PushKit
import SkyWay
```

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate, CXProviderDelegate, PKPushRegistryDelegate {

```
override init() {
    super.init()

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    print("\(UUIDs)========UUIDs=======")
    print("\(UUID())========UUID=======")

}





func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // PushKit
    let registry = PKPushRegistry(queue: nil)
    registry.delegate = self
    registry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushType.voIP]

    //  Converted to Swift 4 by Swiftify v4.1.6781 - https://objectivec2swift.com/
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)


    SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)


    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }



    let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken

    print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")


    UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "FCM_TOKEN")
    print("Firebase registration token: \(token)")

    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    Messaging.messaging().isAutoInitEnabled = true

    let onesignalInitSettings = [kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false]


    OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions,
                                    appId: "2e92****************a7f",
                                    handleNotificationAction: nil,
                                    settings: onesignalInitSettings)


    OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayType.notification;

    OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications(userResponse: { accepted in
        print("User accepted notifications: \(accepted)")
    })




    return true
}



// Handle updated push credentials
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {
    // Register VoIP push token (a property of PKPushCredentials) with server
}



func application(application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

    print("sdfksjkjfksajkdnslfs")
}



func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {



    UserDefaults.standard.set(fcmToken, forKey: "FCM_TOKEN")
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}


func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
}



func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application,
                                                     open: url,
                                                     sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                     annotation: annotation)
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo["gcm.message_id"] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo["gcm.message_id"] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}








}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    if let messageID = userInfo["gcm.message_id"] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")

        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])

    }


    print(userInfo)



}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    if let messageID = userInfo["gcm.message_id"] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    print(userInfo)


}
}
```

Comment: Have you tired from Firebase console?

Comment: when you run the app, that " print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")") " is printing the token?

Comment: @ Amir Khan 
Yes I have. and nothing happened actually.

Comment: @Vincent Joy
Yes It is printing the token.

Comment: try it with token in postman and check what error you are getting.

Comment: @Dharmesh sending request using Postman returned like "{
    "message_id": 8306099********
}". It means, connection between Postman server and Firebase has no probrem right? When it comes to it, there should be some mistakes in my codes??

Comment: yes and what payload you are trying to send via notification?

Comment: @Dharmesh First try payload(Body) is → {
    "to" : "/topics/ios",
    "priority" : "high",
    "notification" : {
        "content_available" : true
    }
}

and returned "{ "message_id": 8306099******** }".

Comment: there should be "title" and "body" key into "notification" key

Comment: Second try payload(Body) is → {"data":{"data": "postmanからpush通知"},
 "to":"cRd02K8vNec:APA91bH0HgBwd3BRUQPRlq1VC5LawNaeHhkh6cbgIRDH_Yep0*************kEBDASh-TKPSMame1xOWWFtklwLXDPu-v2waGotqr9IUaalRNDCSzUq_X"
}

and return like "{
    "multicast_id": 81502983*****5948799,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1554014674********7e7ff9fd7ecd"
        }
    ]
}"

Comment: > there should be "title" and "body" key into "notification" key 
Got it.

Comment: try this: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fwznJjyMjB/

Comment: @Dharmesh

provided codes returned → {
    "multicast_id": 64***********915,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1554015175********75f97e7f75f97e7f"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190975/discussion-between-dharmesh-and-ryoma-kishimoto).